# Permission denied, forever.js as a bash script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, bash, forever

So I figured out how to run forever in a bash script, in filezilla I changed all permissions for `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever` to 777.

**post-receive bash script**

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/example.io/public_html --git-dir=/var/repo/example.git checkout -f
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever restart ../../../www/example.io/public_html/server.js
```

Then when I push it writes successfully but I get this

```
remote: hooks/post-receive: 3: hooks/post-receive: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever: Permission denied
```

So since I changed all folders to 777, what else can I do?

Comment: The forever executable itself has to be executable even if the folder is 777

Comment: I 777 everything inside the forever folder, I am still getting permission denied?

Comment: What if you cd to the dir first then run forever

Comment: cd inside the bash script?

Comment: Any ideas, I am still getting the permission denied?

Comment: What does the `forever` file look like? Specifically what does its shebang (`#!`) line look like?

Comment: `cd /var/www/example.io/public_html` then run forever
`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever restart server.js`

Comment: @MichaelPeppler I am trying to run it as a bash script inside post-receive so that when I run git push it will do it by itself. I dont want to have to ssh into my server and do it manually.

Comment: @EtanReisner If I am looking at the correct file you are talking about it is javascript. https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/blob/master/lib/forever.js maybe you speak of a different file?

Comment: If that's the file then the problem is that you are trying to run it directly. It has no shebang (`#!`) line to tell the shell how to run the file. Should you be using the [forever node script](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/blob/master/bin/forever) there instead?

Comment: Oh okay I did not know that. Let me try that, thanks.

Comment: Thanks it worked but now I am back to my other issue `remote: error:   Error restarting process: var/www/example.io/public_html/server.js
remote: error:   Cannot find forever process: var/www/example.io/public_html/server.js` For some reason I cant get the path to my server.js right, what am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

So in the bash script the forever command works just like this

```
forever restart server.js
```

No paths involved, the only caveat is it restarts all server.js processes, so I would need to name my node servers accordingly.

Also changed my remote server to root. All is working now.